# Is the new Sitecore 9.2 serialization the same as Rainbow serialization?

Tags: serialization, rainbow

As far as I know Sitecore is introducing a new serialization in version 9.2, but is this the same as Rainbow serialization?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you know [Rainbow](https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Rainbow) is an open source advanced serialization and comparison system for Sitecore which is using a YAML format.

In Sitecore 9.2 there is a new serialization implemented in a YAML format.

So Rainbow and Sitecore 9.2 both using YAML format, but they are not the same.

**Sitecore is not using the Rainbow serialization format!**

Comment: Whats the name of new Serialization? From where can we download Sitecore 9.2?

Comment: There is no name for this serialization. Sitecore 9.2 will be available later in July on https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform.aspx